# WPF DataTrigger - own enum return null in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, triggers, datatrigger

I have this code:

.xaml:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TypeItem}" Value="{x:Static local:CListBoxItem+ETypeItem.File}">
    ...
</DataTrigger>
```

.cs:

```
public CListBoxItem(ETypeItem _type)
{
    this.TypeItem = _type;
    InitializeComponent();
}

...

public enum ETypeItem { File,  Directory }

...

public static readonly DependencyProperty TypeItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TypeItem", typeof(ETypeItem), typeof(CListBoxItem), new PropertyMetadata(ETypeItem.Directory));
public ETypeItem TypeItem
{
    get { return (ETypeItem) GetValue(TypeItemProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TypeItemProperty, value); }
}
```

When i run app my style don't work. When i use:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TypeItem}" Value="{x:Null}">
    ...
</DataTrigger>
```

Then work.. How to make the TypeItem load with own style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `CListBoxItem` class is derived from `ListBoxItem` or `Control` try `Trigger` instead of `DataTrigger` (and static value `Value="{x:Static local:CListBoxItem+ETypeItem.File}"`). DataTrigger search for property in DataContext and not in object itself.